# Passing Variable into JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Right now I am trying to pass a Variable to a Javascript but its not showing the value that I pass..

This is my code:

```
<script>
function printPage(school_number)
{
    var school_number;  
    alert(school_number);

}
</script>
```

I am passing the value 0211

```
<body onLoad="printPage(0211);">
```

the alert is showing 155.. Why and where is the number getting changed?

Comment: `0` prefixed means octal.

Comment: but my alert saying 137 instead of 155 ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your number isn't being changed, rather it's exactly what you've defined it as -- an 'octal' number. When you begin a number with 0, it will actually represent that value as base-8 (as opposed to base-10 -- decimal -- which you're used to).

If you just want to output the string literal '0211', simply put quotes around it:

```
<body onLoad="printPage('0211')">
```

and if you want to show the number 211, just remove the 0:

```
<body onLoad="printPage(211)">
```

One other obvious thing I didn't catch on my first answer: you don't need to redeclare your `var`, if you're already passing it in as a parameter. Remove that `var school_number;` from your function.

Comment: Thank you, for the quick response. I converted the number to a string and will use it as such moving forward

Answer (score 3):

you are redefining the variable, and passing 0xx `octal number`...

```
<script>
function printPage(school_number)
{
    alert(school_number);

}
</script>


<body onLoad="printPage('0211');">
```

Comment: Redeclaring a variable within the same scope is not an issue in Javascript.

Comment: @Paulpro but here it's unnecessary

Comment: @JordiCastilla True, but it has nothing to do with the OP's problem, and before your edit your answer didn't mention the octal number. It still doesn't really explain what an octal number is, or link anywhere that explains it.